# Make changes in an NSURL

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsurl

I try to insert something within an NSURL. I get my URL from a jSon string:

```
imageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[[jsonPost objectAtIndex:countPage] objectForKey:@"excerpt"]];
```

The imageURL now contains the following:

```
http://www.site.com/images/uploads/2011/04/2010-12-14-image.gif
```

What i try to achieve is to change the URL to:

```
http://www.site.com/images/uploads/2011/04/2010-12-14-image_r.gif
```

So there will be _r added right before the extension.

Answer (score 4):

method 1:(works ok if you know the file extension to be `.gif`)

```
NSString *string = [[jsonPost objectAtIndex:countPage] objectForKey:@"excerpt"]];
NSArray *array = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@".gif"]; //separated by dot
NSString *editedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_r.gif",[array objectAtIndex:0]];
NSURL *url = [NSURL urlWithString:editedString];
```

edit:
a more reliable solution:

```
NSRange range;
range.location = 0;//starting from the first character
range.length = string.length - 4;//excluding the last 4 characters
//of course you have to make sure the .extension part is 4 characters long(at least fixed length), not like .torrent or .rmvb
NSString *newString = [urlString substringWithRange:range];//this should give you the url part without the file extension

//then append the newString with something and make your url with this string
```

Comment: Thank you this really pointed me in the right direction!

I used the following code to fix my problem (also solves the image extension problem):

    `NSString *url = [[jsonPost objectAtIndex:countPage] objectForKey:@"excerpt"];`
`NSArray *array = [url componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    NSString *retinaUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@.%@_r.%@",[array objectAtIndex:0], [array objectAtIndex:1], [array objectAtIndex:2], [array objectAtIndex:3]];`
`imageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:retinaUrl];`